# What are the units an magnitudes sensed by a USRP2

Tags: usrp

I just started working with the USRP, so a basic question arise: What are the samples that the USRP2 is sensing?  (units, magnitude)
Note: I already capture some data in a file, but my question remains

Data Example:
0.0029651010408997536, 0.0027672448195517063, 0.0026872570160776377, 0.0026175084058195353, 0.0025307394098490477, 0.0033219337929040194, 0.00809861347079277, 0.010622795671224594, 0.007327878847718239, 0.00381132448092103, 0.0028107648249715567, 0.0026527538429945707, 0.0033667022362351418, 0.003682398237287998, 0.010910660959780216, 0.02414804883301258, 0.02014402113854885, 0.007897491566836834, 0.0037226155400276184, 0.0036899647675454617, 0.004084467887878418, 0.011853039264678955, 0.16679257154464722, 0.8468319177627563, 1.0807441473007202, 0.34814727306365967, 0.03349483758211136, 0.008172730915248394, 0.009116406552493572, 0.006185914855450392, 0.00622738478705287, 0.007180056534707546, 0.008053596131503582, 0.00642054621130228, 0.005508296191692352,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Question:
The samples are delivered to you as IQ pairs - so you are seeing the real and imaginary pairs, each of which is a sample.

Getting Support:
For support, you should really look to the mailing lists:
http://lists.ettus.com/mailman/listinfo/usrp-users_lists.ettus.com

Or, for GNU Radio:
https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/discuss-gnuradio

In general, the community uses the lists almost exclusively for support.

Comment: How can I use that data to calculate the electric field?

Comment: which one is real part, and which one is de imaginary? (in the data  that I posted)